# How can I 'flatten' thousands of paths quickly in a vector image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape

I have a .ai file (also opened fine in Inkscape) with thousands of paths which sometimes overlap.  I would like to have no overlap and just each object.  I will need to simplify it further as I am planning to laser cut/engrave with it but manually cutting and joining is going to take a long time.

It seems I could export as a very high resolution raster image and then trace that but that seems less than proper.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Illustrator:

- Select All
- Click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel** (Window > Pathfinder)

This removes all overlapping areas and combines areas with the same fill color.